# Specific string sorting [Python 2.7]

Tags: string, python-2.7, sorting

I am fairly new to python, and I was trying to sort this string in a certain way (Taken off a database):

```
6392079|||| 1.0|03/09/2017|PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP|INSULIN INFUSION PUMP / SENSOR AUGMENTED|MEDTRONIC MINIMED|18000 DEVONSHIRE STREET||NORTHRIDGE|CA|91325||US|91325||MMT-723LNAH|MMT-723LNAH|||0LP|R|01/29/2014|OYC||Y
```

This is the standard format for these types of strings:

```
MDR_REPORT_KEY|DEVICE_EVENT_KEY|IMPLANT_FLAG|DATE_REMOVED_FLAG|DEVICE_SEQUENCE_NO|DATE_RECEIVED|BRAND_NAME|GENERIC_NAME|MANUFACTURER_D_NAME|MANUFACTURER_D_ADDRESS_1|MANUFACTURER_D_ADDRESS_2|MANUFACTURER_D_CITY|MANUFACTURER_D_STATE_CODE|MANUFACTURER_D_ZIP_CODE|MANUFACTURER_D_ZIP_CODE_EXT|MANUFACTURER_D_COUNTRY_CODE|MANUFACTURER_D_POSTAL_CODE|EXPIRATION_DATE_OF_DEVICE|MODEL_NUMBER|CATALOG_NUMBER|LOT_NUMBER|OTHER_ID_NUMBER|DEVICE_OPERATOR|DEVICE_AVAILABILITY|DATE_RETURNED_TO_MANUFACTURER|DEVICE_REPORT_PRODUCT_CODE|DEVICE_AGE_TEXT|DEVICE_EVALUATED_BY_MANUFACTUR
```

Is there any way I can print out this string sorted with the specific datatype next to the value?
For example as an output I would like to have

```
Report key: 6392079
Device sequence number: 1.0
Date received: 03/09/2017
Brand name: PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP
```

etc.etc. with the other values. I think I would need to use the "|" as a divider to separate the data, but I'm not sure how to. I also cannot use sorting with the index number, because there are many variations of the string above which are all different lengths.

Also as you can see in the string some of the data such as device_event_key, implant_flag, date_removed_flag, and device_sequence number are absent, but there are still corresponding empty vertical slashes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How are you querying the database, seems strange to get the result back as a string like this? You can use `str.split('|')` to split this string but you might want to look into the `csv` module.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look into that. There was instructions on how to perform operations on the database, and the format they provided for download was a pretty large .txt file with strings like this each on new lines

Comment: **@nsortur**, you can use **list comprehension**, **split ()**, **join()** methods on string objects and **zip()** to simultaneously iterate over 2 lists to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `zip` to merge the two lists into tuple pairs:

```
data = '6392079|||| 1.0|03/09/2017|PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP|INSULIN INFUSION PUMP / SENSOR AUGMENTED|MEDTRONIC MINIMED|18000 DEVONSHIRE STREET||NORTHRIDGE|CA|91325||US|91325||MMT-723LNAH|MMT-723LNAH|||0LP|R|01/29/2014|OYC||Y'
format = 'MDR_REPORT_KEY|DEVICE_EVENT_KEY|IMPLANT_FLAG|DATE_REMOVED_FLAG|DEVICE_SEQUENCE_NO|DATE_RECEIVED|BRAND_NAME|GENERIC_NAME|MANUFACTURER_D_NAME|MANUFACTURER_D_ADDRESS_1|MANUFACTURER_D_ADDRESS_2|MANUFACTURER_D_CITY|MANUFACTURER_D_STATE_CODE|MANUFACTURER_D_ZIP_CODE|MANUFACTURER_D_ZIP_CODE_EXT|MANUFACTURER_D_COUNTRY_CODE|MANUFACTURER_D_POSTAL_CODE|EXPIRATION_DATE_OF_DEVICE|MODEL_NUMBER|CATALOG_NUMBER|LOT_NUMBER|OTHER_ID_NUMBER|DEVICE_OPERATOR|DEVICE_AVAILABILITY|DATE_RETURNED_TO_MANUFACTURER|DEVICE_REPORT_PRODUCT_CODE|DEVICE_AGE_TEXT|DEVICE_EVALUATED_BY_MANUFACTUR'
for label, value in zip(format.split('|'), data.split('|')):
    print("%s: %s" % (label.replace('_', ' ').capitalize(), value))
```

This outputs:

```
Mdr report key: 6392079
Device event key:
Implant flag:
Date removed flag:
Device sequence no:  1.0
Date received: 03/09/2017
Brand name: PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP
Generic name: INSULIN INFUSION PUMP / SENSOR AUGMENTED
Manufacturer d name: MEDTRONIC MINIMED
Manufacturer d address 1: 18000 DEVONSHIRE STREET
Manufacturer d address 2:
Manufacturer d city: NORTHRIDGE
Manufacturer d state code: CA
Manufacturer d zip code: 91325
Manufacturer d zip code ext:
Manufacturer d country code: US
Manufacturer d postal code: 91325
Expiration date of device:
Model number: MMT-723LNAH
Catalog number: MMT-723LNAH
Lot number:
Other id number:
Device operator: 0LP
Device availability: R
Date returned to manufacturer: 01/29/2014
Device report product code: OYC
Device age text:
Device evaluated by manufactur: Y
```

Answer (score 1):

**@nsortur**, you can try the below code to get the output.

> I have used the concept of **list comprehension**, **zip()** function and **split()**, **join()** methods defined on string objects.
>
> You can try to run code online at 
>   http://rextester.com/MBDXB29573 (Code perfectly works with Python2/Python3).

```
string1 = "6392079|||| 1.0|03/09/2017|PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP|INSULIN INFUSION PUMP / SENSOR AUGMENTED|MEDTRONIC MINIMED|18000 DEVONSHIRE STREET||NORTHRIDGE|CA|91325||US|91325||MMT-723LNAH|MMT-723LNAH|||0LP|R|01/29/2014|OYC||Y"

keys = ["Report key", "Device sequence number","Date received", "Brand name"];

values = [key.strip() for key in string1.split("|") if key.strip()];

output = "\n".join([key + ": " + str(value) for key, value in zip(keys, values)]);

print(output);
```

**Output**:

```
Report key: 6392079
Device sequence number: 1.0
Date received: 03/09/2017
Brand name: PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by simple `split()` method of the `str`, `split('|')` would have empty strings for the empty values between two `|`, and then match it with `dict` having **attribute** as `key` and **value** as `value` of dict

```
query = '6392079|||| 1.0|03/09/2017|PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP|INSULIN INFUSION PUMP / SENSOR AUGMENTED|MEDTRONIC MINIMED|18000 DEVONSHIRE STREET||NORTHRIDGE|CA|91325||US|91325||MMT-723LNAH|MMT-723LNAH|||0LP|R|01/29/2014|OYC||Y'

def get_detail(str_):
    key_finder = {'Report Key': 0, 'Device Sequence Number': 4, 'Device Recieved': 5, 'Brand Name': 6}
    split_by = str_.split('|')
    print('Report Key : {}'.format(split_by[key_finder['Report Key']]))
    print('Device Seq Num : {}'.format(split_by[key_finder['Device Sequence Number']]))
    print('Device Recieved : {}'.format(split_by[key_finder['Device Recieved']]))
    print('Brand Name : {}'.format(split_by[key_finder['Brand Name']]))

>>> get_detail(query)

Report Key : 6392079
Device Seq Num :  1.0
Device Recieved : 03/09/2017
Brand Name : PARADIGM REAL-TIME REVEL INSULIN INFUSION PUMP
```

This works because the splited string will be indexed from `0`, so the `Report Key` will have the value in 0th index of the splitted string and so on for other values. This will be matched with the `dict` **key_finder** which has the stored index for each value.